# Serverfault - How do I make comments to a _question_?

Tags: support

This looks like a stupid question. I didn't find a button to write comments to a specific question. How can I do that?

Comment: ok... I just found that I can write comments to my own question but not others.

Comment: See the [faq].  You need 50 rep to comment anywhere.

Comment: check this page - http://serverfault.com/privileges and http://serverfault.com/privileges/comment

Comment: That bar that appeared across the top of the page when you first visited SF, prompting you to read the FAQ, is not just an ornament.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I can determine you need to have 50 reputation points before you can have this priv.  You have only 6.  https://serverfault.com/privileges/comment